# Get AndroidTest code coverage in AndroidStudio 3.0

Tags: android, testing, junit, code-coverage, android-testing

I have most of the test of my project in the AndroidTest folder instead of Test because they need to use a lot of Db methods and because my colleagues decided to put them there. Now I can't move them because they'll stop working. But I need to get the code coverage of said tests...

Is there any way to enable code coverage for test under AndroidTest folder? I've been looking but none of the solutions I found work for me.

Note that I also have some Espresso tests that I'd like to get coverage to if it is possible.

Comment: I wrote an article about this: https://github.com/uriel-frankel/android-code-coverage

Comment: @UrielFrankel Hey thanks for the help, but I got stuck at trying to pull the coverage.ec file. It says it doesn't exist even tho I just copied and pasted the 'generated code coverage data to' filepath

Comment: you meant adb pull /data/user/0/com.hellojacoco.app/files/coverage.ec
?

Comment: Yes, it says `adb: error: remote object 'data/user/0/com.patan.gimnasio/files/coverage.ec' does not exist`

Comment: @UrielFrankel do you know why?

Comment: do you had this written in the end of the test? INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: stream= 
Time: 1.621
OK (1 test)
Generated code coverage data to /data/user/0/houzz.com.hellojacoco/files/coverage.ec
INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: coverageFilePath=/data/user/0/houzz.com.hellojacoco/files/coverage.ec
INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: -1

Comment: @UrielFrankel yes

Comment: so if you will do adb pull of what is written in coverageFilePath you should get a file

Comment: @UrielFrankel Yes, except I don't get the file and instead get `adb: error: remote object 'data/user/0/com.patan.gimnasio/files/coverage.ec' does not exist`

Comment: I think you should add / before data

Answer (score 3):

I got a simple command for you.

```
./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

I just found out about this myself. The one problem is that it won't display anything in the Android Studio IDE, which is annoying, and I'm currently looking for a solution to. Instead, it'll instead create a JaCoCo report in the `/app/build/reports/coverage/debug/` folder. I don't know if this'll also pick up espresso tests because I haven't messed with those yet.

Anyway, hope that helped.

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: "gradlew createDebugCoverageReport" worked from the run anything (ctrl-ctrl) window

Comment: That folder does not exist after I ran the command